# Inequality depending on a series and a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, inequality

I know that $ \forall n\in N, a_0 + a_1 + ... + a_n = 1$, with $a_0, a_1, ... a_n > 0$ and 
$f(t) = a_0t^n+a_1t^{n-1}+...+a_n, \forall t\in R$

I have to prove that $$
f\left(\sqrt{x^3} \right)* f\left(\frac1{x^3} \right)\ge1
$$

Sorry, but I do not know where to begin...
What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where to begin..hum : Take a paper and a pen and write ;-).

Comment: ALready did that, sir :D No result...

Comment: For your problem, the following inequality holds though: $$f^2(\sqrt{x^3})f(1/x^3)>1$$ for positive $x$. check the question.

Comment: I posted the question like this because that's how I received it from somebody else, this is the form I received the inequation and this is the form I was said to prove. But now I found out it's false, I don't know what to do next :))

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. 
Take $f(t) = \frac{63t}{64} +\frac{1}{64}$ then

$a=f(\sqrt{4^3} ) =7,890625,$
$b=f\left(\frac{1}{4^3 } \right)=0,031005859375$ but $ab =0,244655609130859375 <1$

Comment: You're right...I wasn't expecting that! :O